# Detect User's timezone in Ruby on Rails 3 without using external web services

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i'm looking for a way to detect the user's timezone given their IP address and long/lat location (via geocode gem).

I've found a lot of solutions on the net but most of them requires external web services such as the timezone gem.

Are there any solution that doesn't require such services (I mean by just local checking)?

Comment: what do you mean by "just local checking"? without using gems or what?

Comment: i mean something that can be done internally within the app itself that doesn't require external web services like earthtools and geonames.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a javascript solution such as [jsTimezoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/).